# cannot find the name "module"

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to run a simple typescript file where I am exporting a function named `sum` as shown below:

I am writing node script.

```
function sum(a:number):number{
  return a;
}
module.exports.sum=sum;
```

I don't understand what I did wrong.

I wrote this simple script to understand the unit test case. I thought if this file is running properly then i will go and start basic test case using mocha and chai.

below is my test code:

```
"use strict"

// Import chai.
let chai = require('chai'),
    path = require('path');

chai.should();

let SampleTest = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'sample.js'));

describe('Sampletesting', () => {
    describe('function sum', function(){
        it('should return number', function(){
            sum(1).should.equal(1);
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Could you please add how are you importing it from the outside?

Comment: @Manu Please find my updated code where i have done simple testing with mocha and chai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This peace of code is working fine for me;

let's say we have a module called `math_utils.ts` which exports a function named `foo` and an object called `obj`

```
 // typescript syntax for exporting 
 export function foo(a: number): number {
    // whatever
 }

 export const obj = { life: 42 }

 const _aPrivateObjectToTheModule = {}

 function _aPrivateFunctionToTheModule() {}
```

Now we define in the same folder another file, for example `math_utils.spec.ts`, which is going to import our module.

```
import { should } from 'chai'
import { foo } from './math_utils'
// now we are able to call math_utils.foo()

describe('foo', () => {
    it('should....', () => {
        foo(1).should.equal(1);
    })
})
```

Now, just for summary, in typescript you can import module members this way... or import the whole module as following:

```
import * as chai from 'chai'
import * as MathUtils from './math_utils' 
// now in an object called MathUtils we have every member defined with the keyword export
const should = chai.should

describe('foo', () => {
    it('should....', () => {
        MathUtils.foo(1).should.equal(1);
    })
})
describe('obj', ()=> {
   // ...
   MathUtils.obj
})
```

Comment: here in  import * as MathUtils from './math_utils'   "MathUtils" refers to?

Comment: One more thing I have cracked why you used MathUtils there but when i run my test i am getting another error as "unexpected reserved word " and  it is pointing "import"

Comment: Seems something related with your configuration... may be you forgot something related with the compiler options? I use Visual Code (the free one) and I always need a file called `tsconfig.json` in the project root. [Visual Code reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript)